# Custom missing function

Tags: r

`missing` returns `TRUE` for an argument not supplied by the caller regardless of whether the argument has a default value.

```
f <- function(a, b=2, c) {
   cat(missing(a), missing(b), missing(c), fill=TRUE)
}

f(a=1)
# FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

I'd like a version of `missing` that returns `TRUE` only for unsupplied arguments that don't have default values. I've come up with something, but it's kind of ugly.

```
really.missing <- function(x) {
    name.supplied <- as.character(substitute(x))
    do.call(function(y) missing(y), 
            unname(mget(name.supplied, envir=parent.frame())))
}
ff <- function(a, b=2, c) {
   cat(really.missing(a), really.missing(b), really.missing(c), fill=TRUE)
}
ff(a=1)
# FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Is there a more concise way?

Comment: `if(missing(a)){TRUE}`?

Comment: You wrote, "I'd like a version of missing that returns TRUE only for unsupplied arguments that don't have default values." `if(missing(a)) TRUE` will do that, when `a` is a function argument.

Comment: `if (missing(a)) TRUE` is equivalent to `missing(a)` except that it returns `NULL` when `a` is supplied. I want a function that will return `FALSE` when `a` is supplied or it has a default value, and `TRUE`, otherwise.

Comment: No, it's exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, how about this:

```
noval<- function(x) {
  tryCatch( {force(x); FALSE}, error = function(x) TRUE)
}

f <- function(a, b=2, c) {
  cat(noval(a), noval(b), noval(c), fill=TRUE)
}

f(a=1)
```

This `noval` function will force your parameter to be evaluated (which will succeed if it passed in or has a default value set but fail otherwise) and return FALSE/TRUE accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, `tryCatch` is simpler. In fact, you don't even need `force`.

Comment: You're right, that's even simpler. I'd personally probably keep it in for clarity.